# React.js Visa Checkout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use Visa Checkout with my simple online shop on React with Redux.

But the problem is - from Visa Checkout [docs](https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/visa_checkout/docs#adding_visa_checkout_to_your_web_page) I should place raw JS function `onVisaCheckoutReady()` as `<script>` inside my html page. So I cannot just place it in `render()`. Also, from docs, I have to listen inside that function for Visa response and somehow send it to my server and process it - it means, there should be a possibility to communicate between my component and that function.

What is the right way to use Visa Checkout with React.js?

Comment: It looks like the docs say it creates a widget? knowing that it doesnt seem like it would be compatible with react, the only way i can think of to render the dynamically generated widget is create an iframe and point to the url to the html page on your server that has what the docs say to put